# How to use latest version of Caffe in DIGITS?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

The Caffe from NVidia is older than BVLC/Caffe. How can I use the latest version of Caffe in NVidia DIGITS?

Comment: I think there are some other differences. For instance, I think BatchNorm is not implemented in the same way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either set the `CAFFE_ROOT` environment variable, or install your build of Caffe to PATH and PYTHONPATH.

https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/digits-5.0/docs/BuildCaffe.md#download-source
https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/digits-5.0/docs/Configuration.md#environment-variables

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using "NVIDIA/caffe" without any problem however when I use BVLC/Caffe I have problem and several layers does not work. I want to use triplet loss for face recognition.